# Django models in admin interface

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have relations as follows:

[image]

***My farmer is essentially a default Django user with some additional attributes.*** I want to implement ***farmer is-a user*** relationship.

My models.py looks like following:

```
class Farmer(models.Model):
  #Field for refering the default user
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, null=True)
  #Field for storing first name of the farmer 
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  #Field for storing last name of the farmer 
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  #Field for storing birth date of the farmer 
  birth_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
  #Field for storing address of the farmer
  address = models.TextField()
  #Field for storing farmer's email
  email = models.EmailField()
  #Field for storing farmer's telephone number
  phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
  phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], blank=True, max_length=20) # validators should be a list

class Farm(models.Model):
 #Field for refering to the owner of the farm
 who_farmer = models.ForeignKey(Farmer, blank=True, null=True)
 #Field for storing address of the farm
 address = models.TextField()
 #Field for storing size of the farm in hectors
 farm_size = models.IntegerField()
 #Field for storing Latitude of the farm
 latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
 #Field for storing Longitude of the farm
 longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
```

***Question 1:*** Is it the correct way to have User as a ForeignKey in Farmer class?

***Question 2:*** In my admin interface when I add a new farmer my farmer is created as follows:
[image]

Why does it save as Farmer object and not with the user I selected/ name of the farmer? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `OneToOneField` looks correct to me. You could use a foreign key, but then you could have multiple farmers pointing to the same user.

To change the way the farmer is displayed in the admin, define a `__str__` method (or `__unicode__` if you're using Python 2).

```
class Farmer(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Comment: Doing this gives me __str__ returned non-string (type User) error. Should return statement return something else?

Comment: As the error days, the method should return a string. I've changed the example, but it's really up to you to choose what you want to include in the output. If you want to display many fields in the admin, look at `list_display` as neosergio suggests.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you need to consider the following documentation:
   [Specifying a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) in official documentation.
2. You should read [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options) options, specially [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) option.

See [a full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) in django documentation.